# DataStage Designer. Export only selected columns to table

Tags: data-warehouse, cognos, datastage, data-export

I have a problem with the "Transformer"-State in the DataStage Designer (version 11.5).
I want to import a table and export only selected columns.

[image]

It works without errors with a sequential file. But when exporting to a table, the entire table is transferred and not just the selected columns. The mapping of the columns in the Transformer-State is the same for both variants.

Does anyone know this error and how to fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right you try to move only a subset of columns from one table to another. 
My first advise would be to limit the the number of columns you select in the ImportDB_Table source stage.

Regarding your problem - RTC (Runtime Column Propagation) could be the reason that you see more columns in the output. RTC will dynamically map all columns from the input and you have to explicitly specify only those columns which a treted in a special way.

Check out the job properties oif runtime column propagation is enabled and disable it. 
Disable also the RTC setting within the TRANSFORMER stage - found in the Transformer stage properties.